# The graph doesnt have the same x and y dimension? I dont understand

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

It was working previously but now it doesn't; I haven't changed anything and I don't know what's wrong. I've looked around but can't find an answer. It's probably something stupid but I can't find it and been sitting here for hours.

Error Message: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (8,) and (9,)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


numrange = range(0,360)
theta = numrange[0::45]
r = [-2.000, -2.000, -1.561, -1.592, -0.597, -2.000, -2.000, -0.187, -2.000]

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r)
ax.set_rmax(1)
ax.set_rticks([-2, -1.5, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2])
ax.set_rlabel_position(-22.5)
ax.grid(True)

ax.set_title("A line plot on a polar axis", va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `numrange[::45]` only has 8 points. If you want to join the lines up, you'll need to append an additional zero (or 360) on the end, alternatively, use `range(0, 361, 45)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your numrange generates the following values for theta:

```
[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315]
```

and your r looks like this:

```
[-2.0, -2.0, -1.561, -1.592, -0.597, -2.0, -2.0, -0.187]
```

length of theta is 8 and length of r is 9.

You either can remove one value of r or you just change the numrange to (0,361):

```
numrange = range(0,361)
```

to get the 360 degree value in your rotary axis:

```
[0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360]
```